# How to visualize cycle times of a periodic process?

Tags: grafana

I have a periodic backend process and I would like to visualize the history of the length of cycles on my dashboard. Is it possible?

I have full control over the data/metrics I generate, so I could perhaps increment a counter every time a cycle completes (a cycle takes about 3 days), so I would get counter updates every 3 days or so. Then how could I get Grafana to report the length of each cycle? (for instance: 72h; 69h; 74h; etc.) The actual widget doesn't matter, but I need something visual to tell me at once if cycles are getting faster or slower.

Any pointers or ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a standard time series: `X-axis - time`, `Y-axis - duration [s]`:
[image]

Then you may add:

- trend line
- aggregations (min/max/avg/derivation/diff/...)
- moving average
- other math functions, which are available in used datasource

Comment: Where does the duration come from? That's the question.

Comment: Duration = cycle duration and it so coming from `I have full control over the data/metrics I generate`

Comment: Well if I could do that then there would be no problem to solve.